# Are the starting conditions in Mass Effect 2 for PS3 the same as other platforms?

Tags: ps3, mass-effect-2

I was reading through the answers to the following questions:

- [Do I need to have played Mass Effect to enjoy Mass Effect 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7405/do-i-need-to-have-played-mass-effect-to-enjoy-mass-effect-2)
- [Should I continue one of my Mass Effect playthroughs in Mass Effect 2 or start afresh?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/should-i-continue-one-of-my-mass-effect-playthroughs-in-mass-effect-2-or-start-af)

And there's a compelling argument that not only should one play *Mass Effect* prior to *Mass Effect 2*, one should play it on the same platform so you can transfer your *Mass Effect* save and change the starting conditions of the game: from different (better?) backstories, to more characters being accessible, to better resources.

This is, of course, similar to other BioWare titles like *Dragon Age II*, where different quests are accessible depending on your actions from *Dragon Age: Origins*.

The problem is: there is no *Mass Effect* for PlayStation 3, so there's no way to import a save to unlock all the "New Game Plus"-esque features.

So when one starts a *Mass Effect 2* game on PlayStation 3, is it any different than starting a clean new game on the PC or Xbox 360? Or is there a system like in *Dragon Age II* where you can select your backstory?

Comment: According to [BioWare FAQ](http://masseffect.bioware.com/info/faq/#me2_ps3), "Mass Effect 2 featured a save game import on PC and X360, how will this work on PS3?
    * Specific details regarding the PS3 version will be made at a later date."

Comment: @Ragnar that's not very helpful, as Mass Effect 2 for PS3 came out 2.5 months ago.

Comment: I know, and I'm sorry about that, but that's what the official FAQ says...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would definitely recommend playing the first game before the second if you can - the story is great and unless it's been accidentally spoiled, there are several twists and turns that make it really worthwhile. Just when you think you've figured it out and you think you're sooo clever, it'll surprise you :)

Though as you say, there *is* no Mass Effect 1 on PS3. There is however, a sort-of solution to not having a save game - there's an interactive motion comic that takes you through the major plot points and lets you make most, if not all, of the big decisions from the first game. The comic is included with the PS3 version of the game so you'd be good to go.

Btw, if you have a decent PC I'd recommend playing it on that instead. The graphics are better, the gameplay is a lot smoother because you don't have to keep pausing to use powers, and you still can't beat mouse + keyboard! :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a PS3, no 360 and no PC capable of running the original Mass Effect, so I played Mass Effect 2 on the PS3 without playing Mass Effect 1 first. While I had a fantastic time playing it, I feel as though I missed out on the full impact of some of the events of Mass Effect 2 as I didn't get the context I would have received from playing Mass Effect 1.

The interactive comic only has 6 "decision points" so you would not be able to replicate all the decisions you made in Mass Effect 1 (which would be carried across if you could load a save game).

Comment: While there are 6 major "decision points" that the game points out to you at the bigining, it appears that the minor dicisions points are also carried over.  This is eveident in conversations with characthers throughout Mass Effect 2.

Comment: That's what I meant - lots of your decisions will be transferred if you play ME1 and import your game in to ME2 (i.e. on the PC or 360). If you play ME2 on the PS3 then you will only be able to make 6 "ME1 decisions" (in the interactive comic).